# Append multiple data arrays to data points

Tags: javascript, arrays, d3.js

I have two data arrays that compliment one another. One array holds the coordinates, whereas the other array holds unique data to that team.

My idea is that when a data point is clicked, index 0 of that array is printed to a (text)box at the bottom of the screen. Then in turn, when that data point is clicked, it also displays the contents of the secondary array below it's team name. However, from my limited knowledge, you can't use two data sets within the same variable.

I'm not looking for the answer to be given to me, but rather some knowledge and direction of D3 works when wanting to use multiple data sets on the same element.

```
var dataPoints = [["Arsenal",-0.0032967741593940836, 0.30399753945657115],["Chelsea", 0.2752159801936051, -0.0389675484210763], ["Liverpool",-0.005096951348655329, 0.026678627680541075], ["Manchester City",-0.004715381791104284, -0.12338379196523988], ["Manchester United",0.06877966010653305, -0.0850615090351779], ["Tottenham",-0.3379518099485709, -0.09933664174939877]];

var teamData = [["Arsenal", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"], ["Chelsea", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"], ["Liverpool", "l", "m", "m", "o", "p"], ["Manchester City", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"], ["Manchester United", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"], ["Tottenahm", “1", "2", "3", "4", "5"]];

var circles = svg.selectAll("circle")
    .data(data)
    .enter()
    .append("circle")
    .attr("r", 7)
    .attr("cx", function(d) { return xScale(d[1]); })
    .attr("cy", function(d) { return yScale(d[2]); })
    .on('click', function(d, i) {
        console.log("click", d[0]);
    })
    .attr("fill", function(d) {
        var result = null;

        if (data.indexOf(d) >= 0) {
            result = colours(d);
        } else {
            result = "white";
        }
        return result;               
    });

var textBox = svg.append("g")
        .attr("transform", "translate(5,385)");

    textBox.append("rect")
        .attr("height", 150)
        .attr("width", 509)
        .style("stroke", bordercolor)
        .style("fill", "none")
        .style("stroke-width", border);

    circles.on("click", function(d) {
        textBox.append("text")
        .attr("x", 10)
        .attr("y", 20)
        .text(d[0])
    })
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The adequate solution here is merging the two data sets, so each element has a datum which is complete.

However, an easy workaround is filtering one array based on the other. For instance, filtering the `teamData` array based on the `dataPoints` array and logging the result:

```
function filter(d) {
    console.log(teamData.filter(e => e[0]===d[0])[0])
}
```

Here is a simple demo, the paragraphs are created using the `dataPoints` array as the data. Click on them to get the corresponding team on the `teamData` array:

```js
var dataPoints = [
  ["Arsenal", -0.0032967741593940836, 0.30399753945657115],
  ["Chelsea", 0.2752159801936051, -0.0389675484210763],
  ["Liverpool", -0.005096951348655329, 0.026678627680541075],
  ["Manchester City", -0.004715381791104284, -0.12338379196523988],
  ["Manchester United", 0.06877966010653305, -0.0850615090351779],
  ["Tottenham", -0.3379518099485709, -0.09933664174939877]
];

var teamData = [
  ["Arsenal", "a", "b", "c", "d", "e"],
  ["Chelsea", "f", "g", "h", "i", "j"],
  ["Liverpool", "l", "m", "m", "o", "p"],
  ["Manchester City", "q", "r", "s", "t", "u"],
  ["Manchester United", "v", "w", "x", "y", "z"],
  ["Tottenahm", "1", "2", "3 ", "4", "5"]
];

d3.select("body").selectAll(null)
  .data(dataPoints)
  .enter()
  .append("p")
  .text(d => d[0])
  .on("click", filter);

function filter(d) {
  console.log(teamData.filter(e => e[0] === d[0])[0])
}
```

```html
<script src="https://d3js.org/d3.v5.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: That's interesting... Do you mind telling me the syntax of this `console.log(teamData.filter(e => e[0] === d[0])[0])`? In particular the `[0]` at the end. How does that return the contents of the array? And secondly, do you have any references for merging this data effectively?

Comment: Filter returns an array, so using `[0]` we get the object inside the array. For merging the arrays there are several Q/A here at stack overflow, just search using [tag:javascript], without D3. At te end it depends on the outcome you want.

Comment: After playing around with this solution, it does work. But it makes my life a lot harder when it comes to customising what it displays. As it returns objects, I can't use the join() method to alter the commas between each index. Nor make use of index[0] of dataPoints as a header within the textBox. Thanks though

Comment: My apologies, the join() method does work (i was forgetting to save it's state) - Cheers